# Run Powershell script that prompts for credentials before running command against remote device

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to get a list of installed programs on another computer in our domain, which requires my domain admin credentials.

```
$Name = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter Computer Name'
Start-Process powershell -Credential "company\adminusername" 

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Name -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms | Select DisplayName, Version | Sort-Object Name
```

I don't know if this is correct or not. But it tells me my username and password is incorrect. Which is false. I must be doing something wrong here.

When I write scripts. I literally just want to double click on them, and let them fly. I'm trying to avoid running a script just to open another script as admin.

Comment: Based on what you've given, I think you want to run the script using powershell rather than trying to invoke it alone. Do something like this in your shortcut target : `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -File "C:\yourfile.ps1"`

Comment: Why not just use `Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $Name -Class Win32Reg_AddRemovePrograms -Credential "company\adminusername" | Select DisplayName, Version | Sort-Object Name`?

Comment: Thanks Drew, that worked. I keep forgetting that quite a few commands allow me to specify a credential. But would you know how I could get my credentials cached when I run a script? They'll be getting more complicated from here on out. 

The command will only be run on my personal device, it wouldn't be accessible by anyone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding a great solution here that not only allows me to get credentials but store them permanently for importing later for use in other scripts as well, with option to encrypt the credential file if needed:

https://www.jaapbrasser.com/quickly-and-securely-storing-your-credentials-powershell/

Answer (score 1):

To hold your credentials:

```
$cred = Get-Credential
```

Then use the $cred variable when you need to.